# Merge tags windows-10 and win10

Tags: discussion, feature-request, retag-request, tags

I have recently noticed that, there is a tag named [win10](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/win10) which has a few questions on Windows 10. But there is already the major tag [windows-10](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-10) and questions should use the major tag. I personally edited 2 questions to remove that. And it would be highly helpful if the [win10](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/win10)'s questions be merged with [windows-10](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-10).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Done.

[win10](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/win10) has been merged into and synonymised with [windows-10](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-10).